# I need a regex pattern which matches the following Hello, World, Hello World

Tags: regex

I need a regex pattern which matches the following "Hello", "World", "Hello World", "HelloWorld", "Hello/World"

Comment: This is not a wish machine.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck finding one. Did you have a question?

Comment: This is insanely easy, google regex or browse for a small tutorial.

Comment: @ anubhava Yes i have tried this Hello(\s|\/|)World it matches every thing except "Hello", "World" individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about the leanest you can get with that:

`Hello(?:[ /]?World)?|World`

Expanded:

```
   Hello (?: [ /]? World )?
|  World
```

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to answer questions accurately when they aren't. You should provide better questions to receive better answers.

This is fairly simple:

```
(Hello)?\s?(World)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

As you can see, this pattern is composed of multiple optional patterns, so it can also match an empty string. So, if you want to have at least one pattern matching, you could do:

```
Hello\s?World|Hello|World
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: When u say (Hello)? it would also accept null, it doesnt work

Comment: @RaghavendraDillikar Regexes match patterns, so you have to think that "null" is basically an empty string. So, `(Hello)?` pattern means that the characters `Hello` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a bit tricky but I was successful to do it totally right. So I share my Regular Expression with you and I hope it can help:

```
(?m)^(?(?=\110\x65\x6c{2}\157)(?:\110\x65\x6c{2}(?P<o>\157)[\x20\x2f]?\127\k'o'\x72\x6c\x64|\110\x65\x6c{2}\157$)|\127\157\x72\x6c\x64$)
```

[Here is an online demo](https://regex101.com/r/nL6rE5/2)

Explanations:

```
(?m)    # Enabling multi-line (For me only to show you how it works on input strings)
^   # Beginning of line
(?  # Beginning an IF condition
    (?=\110\x65\x6c{2}\157) # Positive Lookahead. IF '\110\x65\x6c{2}\157' was found...
    (?: # Start of a non-capturing group
        \110\x65\x6c{2}(?P<o>\157)[\x20\x2f]?\127\k'o'\x72\x6c\x64  # Then match '\110\x65\x6c{2}(?P<o>\157)[\x20\x2f]?\127\k'o'\x72\x6c\x64'
        |   # Otherwise
        \110\x65\x6c{2}\157 # Match '\110\x65\x6c{2}\157'
        $   # End of line
    )   # End of non-capturing group
|   # IF condition else statement
    \127\157\x72\x6c\x64    # Match '\127\157\x72\x6c\x64'
    $   # End of line
)   # End of IF condition
```

You may ask if it really works and I'm so excited to say **YES**. You didn't expect a *Hello World* like that? Then welcome to the programmers' *01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100!*

*- By the way, that was a good question.*

Comment: `(?  <-- Quantifies nothing # Beginning an IF condition` Grouping construct delimiters are not expand aware.  For conditionals `(?(..)` the start delimiter is `(?(`

Comment: @sln if `(?(` is supposed as the right beginning delimiter then what is the finishing delimiter? a `))` ?! Well... I don't think!

Comment: It is the delimiter. `(` starts the first level, '?(` starts the second level, `)` ends the second level, `)` ends the first level. That's how regex is parsed.  `(` is bound to the following `?` that triggers a state depending upon the next immediate character(s) following `?`. In this case `?(` triggers a conditional, just as `?#` triggers an extended comment and `?:` triggers a cluster, `?=` an assertion, etc... `(?x)` mode has no affect in the binding of `?` and the next character, otherwise, your line of code would be an extended comment, not a conditional.

Comment: @sln I do agree `?(` as a conditional trigger but not as a delimiter. Delimiter has its own definition. You said `( starts the first level, ?( starts the second level, ) ends the second level, ) ends the first level` but it is right whenever we don't have an else statement. There can be a pipe inside as else statement which causes an interruption in ending delimiter to be `))`. So we can't say it's the delimiter. Delimiters are always remain the same at the very beginning and at the very end. I think you are confusing with meanings.

Comment: That's not correct, delimiters are dynamically added and/or factored out in code. Each code section being responsible for its own ending. You can say `(?` is a delimiter, but to what ? If I have 45 things that start with `(?`, I'm not going to make it the delimiter, I'm gonna make `(` the first level and (in this case) `?(` the second level delimiter (that requires recursion) doing its own balance. Or, I could make `(?(` the first level, stuff all the minutia forms next with a common closure ')` then do the core, followed by another closure `)`. Decent parsing works this way.

Comment: @sln You are saying `(?(` is the IF condition delimiter. Then what will happen if I'm going to use a lookahead expression after it? I mean how about this `(?(?=.)...`? If we just accepted `(?(` as the conditional statement starting delimiter so what's the starting delimiter of that lookahead? Is `?=` a delimiter? It's not a delimiter because an expression should be enclosed with the same delimiter and it won't happen to it. `(?=.)` alone is what we call a lookahead expression and if we omit its opening parentheses - as the delimiter of previous expression (IF) - we are messing up definitions.

Comment: Yes, `(?(` can be a start delimiter, where `)` is the end. Example `\(\?\((?:\?(?:=|!|<=|<!))?(?&core)\)(?&core)\)` this covers all assertion and expression conditionals. Broken down startdelimiter = `\(\?\(` middle = `(?:\?(?:=|!|<=|<!))?(?&core)\)(?&core)` enddelimiter `)`. Delimiters are whatever you make them. All the conditional constructs can be wedged into this.

Comment: @sln Sorry but one of us can't understand the other. Anyhow thanks!

Comment: I guess in the final analysis (?`(`?=.)) can't be a delimiter by itself to denote a conditional, neither `(?` , by itself since it says nothing of the construct. Instead of maintaining several different states with duplicate branches all over the place, the constructs are factored as common delimiters with common code paths.